# What's the fastest method to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{4-\sqrt{h}} dh$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Question says it all. I believe there's a very simple method to evaluate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $u = 4-\sqrt h$. Note that $\sqrt h = h^{1/2} = 4-u$.

Then $$\,du = \frac 1{h^{1/2}} \,dh \iff h^{1/2}du = (4-u)\,du = dh$$

So we have the integral $$\int\frac{4-u}{u}\,du = \int \dfrac 4u \,du - \int \,du$$

I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: I'm picking this as best answer because it's the most detailed. Both methods are fast and depending on the skills or strengths of the person doing it either method might be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Set $ h = x^2 $, so that $ \mathrm dh = 2x\,\mathrm dx $, and
$$
\int \frac{1}{4 - \sqrt{h}} \mathrm dh = \int \frac{2x}{4 - x}\mathrm dx,
$$
which is elementary.

You just need to remember to have $ x > 0 $ throughout the computation.

Answer (score 3):

Put $h=x^2$. Then $$I=\int \frac{2x}{4-x}dx=-8\ln (4-x)-2x+C$$